# Dafny How could I write a predicate to prove a string is sorted by 'b' => 'a' => 'd'?

Tags: dafny

Could somebody please help me out in writing a Dafny predicate that checks if a string is sorted in the order 'b' -> 'a' -> 'd'

i.e:

"bbbaaaaad" == true
"abd" == false 
"bad" == true

The predicate should have the following form:

```
predicate sortedbad(s:string) 
{
[???]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the expected answer if there are characters other than 'b', 'a', or 'd'?

Comment: It won't receive characters that aren't either 'b', 'a' or 'd'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

```
predicate bad_compare(c1:char, c2:char) {
  c1 == 'b' || (c1 == 'a' && c2 != 'b') || c2 == 'd'
}

predicate sortedbad(s:string) 
{
  forall i, j | 0 <= i <= j < |s| :: bad_compare(s[i], s[j])
}

lemma Test()
{
  assert sortedbad("bbbbaaaadddd");
  var s := "bbbbbbda";
  assert !bad_compare(s[6], s[7]);
  assert !sortedbad(s);
}
```

Comment: You're actually a legend, ty!!